# What is the earliest source for Kirk's year of birth?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, captain-kirk

By now his year and place of birth (as well as names of family members) are canonical, but I think these come from later movies and books, and the use of stardates has been discussed before.

What is the *earliest* mention of Kirk's year of birth?

---

I personally think general vagueness about the exact time things occur in Star Trek also contributes to a plausibility about the technology that is supposed to have been developed. I know for sure that shows like *Space: 1999* and *Voyage to the Bottom of the Sea* dated themselves irreparably by setting the stories so close to our own in time. *Voyage* with its flying subs etc. occurred more than 40 years ago. No one watches it anymore.

Comment: I've removed some of your thoughts and musings as I don't feel that they contribute anything to the question.

Comment: Ah trek is very futuristic by having Kirk be from Tarsus IV and Zefram Cochrane be from Alpha Centauri.  Technically the first mention of a birth date would be the James R. Kirk tombstone but with stardates. Admittedly the date is nonsense given the rate of decimal stardate progression in the episode I'm sure.  But I note the stardate in Strange New Worlds first episode was off by thousands between the episode start and end - shows how far the writing has fallen

Comment: @lucasbachmann kirk was born in iowa or are u discussing something else?

Comment: Oh you mean 80s star trek

Answer (score 3):

The earliest canonical source for Kirk's date of birth is the TOS episode *[The Deadly Years](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Deadly_Years_(episode))* (1967)

> **COMPUTER:** *Working. Subject's physical age based on physiological profile, between sixty and seventy two. Aging rapidly.*
>
> **KIRK:** *No, I'm thirty four. **I'm thirty four years old.***
>
> **STOCKER:** *The computer differs with you, Captain.*

This episode takes place in [2267](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Deadly_Years_(episode)#:%7E:text=Joseph%20Pevney-,In%2Duniverse%20date,-%E2%86%90), making Kirk's date of birth the **22nd of March, [2233](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/2233).**

Comment: Although, to be fair, that requires a much later aired show to establish the 2233 date, namely 1988 in TNG's "The Neutral Zone" when Data explicitly named the current year as 2364 (the first time a specific date was ever given in Star Trek). All other canon Trek dates (aside from ones where they time-travel to a given year in the past) are based on that episode reference.

Comment: @KeithMorrison - Kirk's DOB was stated (by Gene Roddenberry) to be 2228 in an interview for *The Making of Star Trek* (1968). Clearly the makers of the show had a specific timeframe in mind for TOS much earlier than the TNG era.

Comment: If they had a specific timeframe, they didn't show their work. Dialogue from the different episodes have it taking place anywhere from the 2100s (USAF guard to Kirk in the 1960s threatening to have him locked up for 200 years, Kirk: "That would be about right.") to "The Squire of Gothos" when they comment that Trelane hasn't kept up to touch with human civilization in 900 years, yet Trelane knows about the 1804 Burr-Hamilton Duel and makes Uhura play an 1880 Strauss work, indicating it's taking place in the 28th Century.